# How to list all accounts using ethers.js

Tags: ether, ethers.js

**web3.js** has a function which lists all the accounts but, how can we list all the accounts in **ethers.js**?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `listAccounts` method:

```js
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ProvidersAPI will help you there.  See: https://docs.ethers.io/v3/api-providers.html#web3provider

listAccounts() under Web3Provider is probably what you're looking for.